# electron-forge how to specify a source directory for packaging?

Tags: electron, create-react-app, electron-packager, electron-forge

I've rigged **create-react-app** with the **electron-forge** app and now I need to somehow specify the build folder produced from the CRA for the packaging. That folder should also be served.

Would such a thing be possible with electron-forge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand are you asking how to tell electron-forge which directory to find your source files in for packaging the app.

If so, see: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md

where it describes the options of the

`"config": {
    "forge": {`

object in your package.json file

inside they there is this package config object:

```
  "electronPackagerConfig": {
    "dir": "./src",
```

where you can specify your source folder.

Also, BTW: there you can specify files/file-regexs to be ignored in packaging:

```
    "ignore": [".idea", ".gitignore"]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with electron-forge version 6.0.0-beta.47. This webpage mentions that you cannot overwrite the "dir" property of electron-packager: https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#packager-config

Answer (score 2):

**electron-forge** has no option to specify input folder (project's root folder will be used):

1. Specify `ignore` option to skip folders/files;
2. Use `main` key in
   package.json to specify correct start script.

For example, **package.json** for **vue** project:

```
{
    "name": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    ...
    "config": {
        "forge": {
            "packagerConfig": {
                "ignore": [
                    "^/[.]vs$",
                    "^/public$",
                    "^/src$",
                    "^/[.]browserslistrc$",
                    "^/[.]editorconfig$",
                    "^/tsconfig[.]json$",
                    "[.](cmd|user|DotSettings|njsproj|sln)$"
                ]
            },
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you specify your electron-forge configuration in a Javascript file ([see docs](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration)), you can also provide a function for the ignore filter ([see docs](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#ignore)). This is a lot more flexible than a list of regex patterns; you can implement the ignore function to act as a whitelist of folders to include rather than a blacklist of folders to exclude

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could specify source folder **in script's arg only** (assume /src is the folder with files to package):
`electron-forge package ./src`

That source folder **must contain package.json** with data electron-forge need to package your project. If no package.json will be found or it will not **meet the requirements**, electron-forge will go up to folder with proper package.json and assume it's the actual project folder. As I found in electron-forge sources, it needs at least this data:

```
{ 
  name: cfg.name,
  version: cfg.version,
  author: cfg.author,
  main: "main.js",
  devDependencies: {
    electron: cfg.devDependencies.electron,
    "@electron-forge/cli": cfg.devDependencies["@electron-forge/cli"]
  },
  config: {
    forge: "../forge.config.js"
  }
}
```

In my project I create this package.json by script and use my main package.json as `cfg` in sample above to provide data. Also you could provide forge config as a path to your forge.config.js to avoid of duplicate it.

Also keep in mind electron-forge would package files/dirs **in that folder only**, so neither node_modules nor other external assets will be included. Therefore you need either make bundle of your project with webpack, esbundle etc. or be careful with dependencies and provide it for packaged app.