# Electron Forge stuck on squirrel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, electron, electron-forge

I've been trying to package an electron app but it never goes past this stage:

[image]

I've tried 3 times and every time it takes hours but doesn't finish packaging for squirrel.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "NAME",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "author": "AUTHOR",
  "description": "DESCRIPTION.",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.9.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^19.0.10",
    "electron-compile": "^6.4.4",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.10.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.15.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
    "package": "react-scripts build && electron-forge package",
    "make-mac": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make --platform darwin",
    "make-linux": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make --platform linux",
    "make": "react-scripts build && electron-forge make"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "8.2.0",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "stock_trading_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux",
            "win32"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

An `application` file appears in my `out > win32-x64` folder but it's not an `.exe` file.

I also have a random `out > make > squirrel.windows > x64` folder that doesn't have anything in it.

Comment: testing stuff like `@testing-library/...` and compilation tools like `electron-compile` certainly belongs in devDependencies, since not needed at runtime. So this will already save you bundle size.

Answer (score 4):

The process takes forever because you're packaging your whole app, `node_modules` included.

A quick solution is to add the parameter [`"asar": true`](https://electron.github.io/packager/main/interfaces/Options.html#asar) to you `packagerConfig`<sup>1</sup>. But unless you want to package the non-compiled files, you probably only want to keep the `build` folder.

You already configured your scripts to run a `build` before the `make`. Now, since Electron Forge doesn't give the option to override [`dir`](https://electron.github.io/packager/main/interfaces/Options.html#dir)<sup>2</sup>, you will have to use the [`ignore`](https://electron.github.io/packager/main/interfaces/Options.html#ignore) option to exclude the files and folders you don't want to have in the packaged app<sup>3</sup>.

```
packagerConfig: {
    ignore: [
        "^\\/public$",
        "^\\/src$",
        "^\\/node_modules$",
        "^\\/[.].+",
        // [...]
    ]
},
```

---

<sup>1. For the record, I found mentions of this [here](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer/issues/189), [here](https://dev.to/celludriel/comment/1d640) and [here](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer/issues/220).

2. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration#possible-configuration) → "You can not override the `dir`, `arch`, `platform`, `out` or `electronVersion` options as they are set by Electron Forge internally."

3. See another example with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693381/9718056).</sup>

Comment: If you specify your electron-forge configuration in a Javascript file ([see docs](https://www.electronforge.io/configuration)), you can also provide a function for the ignore filter ([see docs](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/interfaces/electronpackager.options.html#ignore)). This is a lot more flexible than a list of regex patterns; you can implement the ignore function to act as a whitelist of folders to include rather than a blacklist of folders to exclude